# How to get javascript files reference by .NET themes?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, themes

I have in my C#, .NET 3.5 (VS2008) web project's App_Themes directory a theme directory called Theme1. In that directory I have various other directories. Some of theme contain .css files and some contain .js files. In my web pages, which use this theme, the appropriate link tags are rendered, in the HTML, for the .css files, but not the .js files. What am I doing wrong, or do I simply have to share all my .js files across all themes from a centralised directory?

Comment: Can you post an example <script> reference that isn't working correctly?

Comment: It's not the reference that isn't working, it's that ASP.NET doesn't render a script tag at all for the .js files inside the particular theme's directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you place the JS files in your theme directory you can use the Page.Theme name to get the appropriate path for the current theme.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/App_Themes/" + Page.Theme + "/js/script.js") %>"></script>
```

Comment: So, references to .js files are not include in the HTML by ASP.NET when they are placed inside theme directories?

Comment: That is correct. You must individually specify what  to load.

Comment: This does make sense as you're likely to have site-wide and page-specific js